# Space optimised versions of Coin Change and Knapsack Problems in Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have recently been focussing on DP formulation and space optimization in dynamic programming of some problems.
I have gone through the standard questions such as [0-1 Knapsack](https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_d) and [Coin Change](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-2/) problems.

In the space optimization part, I haven't understood in which order should I fill the table to get the desired result. For instance, In the above 0-1 Knapsack Problem, which asks about max possible sum of values for a weight of at most **w**.

```
vector<int> dp(w + 1); // dp[j] max value that can be obtained with weight exactly j
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = w; j >= weight[i]; j--) // iterating from right to left here
      dp[j] = max(dp[j], val[i] + dp[j - weight[i]]);
  }
```

In the above snippet why the ordering is important? I am confused because for the space-optimized version of coin change problem mentioned above we iterate from left to right to get total no. of ways to get change, it goes as @qqibros answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880842/space-optimized-solution-for-coin-change)

```
 vector<int>dp(x+1); // dp[i]- no of ways to get coins with value exactly i
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(int j=a[i];j<=x;j++){ // iterating from left to right here
    dp[j]+=dp[j-a[i]];
  }
  cout<<dp[x]<<endl;
```

But if I change the above coin change problem adding the constraint that every coin can only be used exactly once, I should iterate from right to left to get the required answer.
For example,*N = 4* and S = {1,2,3}, only one solution {1,3} so the output should be 1. And For *N = 10* and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, still only one solution {2, 3, 5} and the output is 1.
Just changing the line from `for(int j=a[i];j<=x;j++)` to `for(int j=x;j>=0;j--)` gives the answer.

I am not able to visualize or interpret correctly how ordering changes the value as in both cases the value only depends on previously stored values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is whether the solution to the "add element `i`" subproblem being considered (`dp[j - weight[i]]` or `dp[j-a[i]]`, as the case may be) allows or forbids a contribution from the *current* element (value of `i`).

When the inner loop moves right-to-left, at the time `dp[j - weight[i]]` is evaluated, that table entry has not yet been updated in this iteration of the outer loop, so it definitely does not include a contribution from element `i`. Thus the candidate solution having value `val[i] + dp[j - weight[i]]` includes *exactly one* copy of element `i` (and the other candidate solution, `dp[j]`, includes exactly zero copies of it).

OTOH, when the inner loop moves left-to-right, at the time `dp[j - weight[i]]` is evaluated, that table entry has already been updated in this outer loop cycle, so it may represent a solution that already contains an element `i`, to which we are now considering adding a second element `i`. In fact it may already contain multiple copies of element `i`, since that table entry may have been computed as the result of choosing `val[i] + dp[j - weight[i] - weight[i]]`, etc.